# Find and replace text in a file after match of pattern only for first occurrence using sed

Tags: linux, bash, sed, text-editing

Let's say I have the following input file:

```
Server 'Test AB'
    option type 'ss'
    option port '1234'
    option timeout '60'

Server 'Test CD'
    option type 'ss'
    option port '1234'
    option timeout '60'

Server 'Test EF'
    option type 'ss'
    option port '1234'
    option timeout '60'

Server 'Test GH'
    option type 'ss'
    option port '1234'
    option timeout '60'
```

And now I want to use sed to exchange "option port '1234'" with "option port '9876'", but I only want to do this for Server 'Test EF'. All the other ports should stay unchanged.

Output should look like:

```
Server 'Test AB'
    option type 'ss'
    option port '1234'
    option timeout '60'

Server 'Test CD'
    option type 'ss'
    option port '1234'
    option timeout '60'

Server 'Test EF'
    option type 'ss'
    option port '9876'
    option timeout '60'

Server 'Test GH'
    option type 'ss'
    option port '1234'
    option timeout '60'
```

I already tried many sed commands, I found out that I can search between lines with

```
sed '11,15s/port '1234'/port '9876'/g' file
```

But this doesn't help me, because Server 'Test EF' won't be always in the same lines. I would need to limit the area instead of 11,15 with for example "'Test EF',option timeout" but no idea how I can realize it.

Comment: What do you mean by “first occurrence”?  Do you mean that there might be multiple `Server 'Test EF'` stanzas?  Or that there might be multiple occurrences of `option port '1234'` within the `Server 'Test EF'` stanza?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Contrary to what [the previous answer](https://superuser.com/a/1689726/150988) says,
this is right up `sed`’s alley. 
And, contrary to another suggestion (now deleted),
it is easily done in a *single* `sed` process.

```
sed "/Server 'Test EF'/,/Server/ s/option port '1234'/option port '9876'/" file
```

will do what you want.

Some say `sed` code is usually quite cryptic,
unless you're a `sed` expert. 
While it may be hard to write,
I believe that it’s fairly easy to read and understand:

- Starting at a line that contains `Server 'Test EF'`,
- and continuing through the next line that contains `Server`,
- search each line for `option port '1234'`
- and, if you find it, substitute `option port '9876'`.

You were actually fairly close. 
Quoting was a big problem with your attempt:
you can’t ***use*** single-quote characters (**`'`**) in a string
that’s also *delimited* with single-quotes
(i.e., that begins and ends with single-quotes). 
One way to handle this (which my answer, above, uses)
is to enclose the string
in double-quote characters (**`"`**); as in

```
  … "…                         … s/option port '1234'/option port '9876'/" …
    ↑                                                                    ↑
```

That works fine if the string doesn’t contain
any **`"`** characters — or `$`, `\` or **`` ` ``**. 
If you’re using bash (as you indicate with your tags),
you can use `$'……\'……'`; e.g.,

```
echo $'the cat\'s pajamas'
the cat's pajamas
```

so you could do

```
  … $'…                     … s/option port \'1234\'/option port \'9876\'/' …
                                            ⇑⇑    ⇑⇑            ⇑⇑    ⇑⇑
```

---

And here’s a much-less-cryptic way of doing it in awk:

```
awk $'
    /Server/             { matched=0 }
    /Server \'Test EF\'/ { matched=1 }
    matched              { gsub("option port \'1234\'", "option port \'9876\'") }
                         { print }
  '
```

- Define a variable called `matched` that is `1`
  (only) when we’re in a `Server 'Test EF'` stanza.
- Set it to `1` when we match `Server 'Test EF'`, …
- … and set it to `0` when we see any other line containing `Server`.
- When `matched` is non-zero
  (i.e., when we’re in a `Server 'Test EF'` stanza),
  search each line for `option port '1234'`
  and substitute `option port '9876'`.

Comment: Thanks a lot! I came back and found the deleted solution here and was not able to make it work. So I continued to "ask" google and was able to come to the exact same solution, using sed like you. Today I wanted to share this solution here and found your answer. Great work and thanks a lot.

Answer (score 0):

This is right up `awk's` ally:

```
awk '$1 ~ q"Test EF"q { $3 = "    option port "q"9876"q } 1' \
  RS= FS='\n' q="'" OFS='\n' ORS='\n\n'
```

By setting `RS` to the empty string, awk reads a whole "record" at a time. By setting `FS` to new-line, every line is a field.

Output:

```
Server 'Test AB'
    option type 'ss'
    option port '1234'
    option timeout '60'

Server 'Test CD'
    option type 'ss'
    option port '1234'
    option timeout '60'

Server 'Test EF'
    option type 'ss'
    option port '9876'
    option timeout '60'

Server 'Test GH'
    option type 'ss'
    option port '1234'
    option timeout '60'
```

Answer (score 0):

```
awk 'NF==/Test EF/ && ++_||!_||(NF = NF)^--_' FS=1234 OFS=9876
```

---

```
Server 'Test AB'
    option type 'ss'
    option port '1234'
    option timeout '60'

Server 'Test CD'
    option type 'ss'
    option port '1234'
    option timeout '60'

Server 'Test EF'
    option type 'ss'
    option port '9876'
    option timeout '60'

Server 'Test GH'
    option type 'ss'
    option port '1234'
    option timeout '60'
```

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).

Comment: @Community : what citations ? i came up with the answer myself. Others can simply run my code to confirm validity of it

Comment: What does this do, how does it work? Can you explain what the parts mean, stuff like `++_||!_||`?