# Find and replace text in a file only after 2 different patterns match using `sed` or `awk`

Tags: linux, bash, regex, sed, replacement

This is an extension of the question asked-and-answered here: [Find and replace text in a file after match of pattern only for first occurrence using sed](https://superuser.com/questions/1689644/find-and-replace-text-in-a-file-after-match-of-pattern-only-for-first-occurrence/1689959#1689959)

The problem being: I need to perform a find-and-replace, but *only* after the first occurrence of `pattern1` followed by `pattern2`. That's where the `pattern3` find and replace must occur.

Using a variation of the sample file from the linked question:

```
Server 'Test AB'
    option type 'sa'
    option port '1234'
    option timeout '60'

Server 'Test AB'
    option type 'sb'
    option port '1234'
    option timeout '60'

Server 'Test EF'
    option type 'sa'
    option port '1234'
    option timeout '60'

Server 'Test GH'
    option type 'sa'
    option port '1234'
    option timeout '60'
```

I need this:

```
Server 'Test AB'
    option type 'sa'
    option port '1234'
    option timeout '60'

Server 'Test AB'
    option type 'sb'
    option port '9876'
    option timeout '60'

Server 'Test EF'
    option type 'sa'
    option port '1234'
    option timeout '60'

Server 'Test GH'
    option type 'sa'
    option port '1234'
    option timeout '60'
```

The first two `Server` names are the same. The `option type` is different for each server. I need to match a specific `Server` name (`Test AB`), and then an `option type` (`sb`), and then change the port number.

I don't know how to make multiple patterns concatenate in a logical `AND`.

Any tips? `sed` or `awk` solutions are preferred (but for the hardcore neckbeards looking for a *real* challenge, try doing it with pure BASH substitution. BASH 5-onwards is fine). Thank you.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`sed` allows you to specify address ranges in a form `addr1,addr2`. The linked answer uses a range. Now you need to nest ranges.

```
sed "
/^Server 'Test AB'$/,/^$/ {
/option type 'sb'/,/option port '/ s/option port '.*'/option port '2222'/
}" file
```

It means: from (and including) a line being `Server 'Test AB'` to (and including) the next empty line apply the code inside `{}`.

And the code inside `{}` means: from (and including) a line containing `option type 'sb'` to (and including) a line containing `option port '` apply  the `s/…/…/` command.

And the `s/…/…/` command means: in each line replace the first occurrence of `option port '.*'` (where `.*` greedily matches zero or more characters) with `option port '2222'`.

Notes:

- It's fortunate there are empty lines we can use to end a range. Without them we would be tempted to specify ranges from `Server` to `Server`. The problem is the first range from `Server 'Test AB'` to the next occurrence of `Server` would include the second occurrence of `Server 'Test AB'`; and in `sed` ranges detected by the same `addr1,addr2` piece of code cannot overlap. In effect the second occurrence of `Server 'Test AB'` would not be treated as the beginning of a new range, so the code inside `{}` would not be executed for lines in this section.
- `^` and `$` are anchors for the beginning and the end of the line respectively. I used them with `Server 'Test AB'` but I deliberately didn't use them with `option type 'sb'`. Adjust the code to your needs.
- I used double-quotes because the data contains single-quotes. Usually you need to escape `$` in double-quotes, but here we have `/` just after each `$`; `$/` is not a valid name for a shell variable nor anything the shell would want to expand, so there is no need to escape `$`.

Comment: Brilliant answer Kamil. :) I had to adapt it to my actual use-case (which has no quotes at-all), and it worked perfectly the first time. Many thanks for including an explanation of the different syntax parts. I suspected a comma or two would be in-there somewhere. I've accepted this as the answer and upvoted it, but I have very low rep at the moment.